# Trying to draw each quicksort iteration on canvas

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript, quicksort

I'd like to see live quicksort iterations on a canvas.

[Here is the small project I'm working on.](https://github.com/sefo/sortsimu/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts)

The problem I'm having is that it draws the initial shuffled state and the sorted state without the steps in between.

```
  quickSort(initArray, metaLeft, metaRight) {
    if (initArray.length <= 1) { 
        return initArray;
    } else {
        var left = [];
        var right = [];
        var newArray = [];
        var pivot = initArray.pop();
        var length = initArray.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (initArray[i] <= pivot) {
                left.push(initArray[i]);
            } else {
                right.push(initArray[i]);
            }
        }
        // console.log([].concat(metaLeft, left, pivot, right, metaRight));
        this.wait();
        this.draw([].concat(metaLeft, left, pivot, right, metaRight));
        var sortedLeft = this.quickSort(left, metaLeft, [pivot].concat(right, metaRight))
        var sortedRight = this.quickSort(right, metaLeft.concat(sortedLeft, pivot), metaRight)
        return newArray.concat(sortedLeft, pivot, sortedRight);
    }
  }
```

I believe it is because of quicksort being recursive but I don't know why and how I could make this work.

The console.log right before the wait / draw functions apparently shows the correct steps I need to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your call to the `wait()` function doesn’t do any waiting. You can make `quickSort()` async too:

```
async quickSort(initArray, metaLeft, metaRight) {
    if (initArray.length <= 1) { 
        return initArray;
    }

    let left = [];
    let right = [];
    let pivot = initArray.pop();
    let length = initArray.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (initArray[i] <= pivot) {
            left.push(initArray[i]);
        } else {
            right.push(initArray[i]);
        }
    }

    await this.wait();
    this.draw([].concat(metaLeft, left, pivot, right, metaRight));
    let sortedLeft = await this.quickSort(left, metaLeft, [pivot].concat(right, metaRight))
    let sortedRight = await this.quickSort(right, metaLeft.concat(sortedLeft, pivot), metaRight)
    return [].concat(sortedLeft, pivot, sortedRight);
}
```

updating calls to it to use promises accordingly:

```
this.quickSort(this.lines, [], []).then(sortedLines => {
    this.lines = sortedLines;
});
```

Converting it to an in-place quicksort would also help make things more natural, getting rid of `metaLeft` and `metaRight` and allowing you to ignore the final promise.